# Rewrite link category wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

How to make rewrite link category in wordpress.
 
http://example.com/orenda-avto?car=econom replace on http://example.com/orenda-avto/econom

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_mypage_rule' );
function add_mypage_rule(){
   add_rewrite_tag("%car%", '(\d+)');
   add_rewrite_rule('^orenda-avto/([^/]*)/?','index.php?cat=22&car=$matches[1]','top');
}
```

And how change title and description on site after get request?

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite link with Permalinks

[image: Permalinks1]

Or you can do it with .htaccess code or yoast plugin

[image: Permalinks2]

Comment: I am creating a get request to the category page, and it can't be changed from the admin page

Comment: I've tried this code `RewriteRule ^orenda-avto/([^/])/?$ orenda-avto?car=$1 [L,QSA]`, but it didn't work

Comment: ok try this RewriteRule   ^orenda-avto/(.+)$   orenda-avto?car=$1   [L]

Comment: Don't work `^orenda-avto/(.+)$ orenda-avto?car=$1 [L]`